# calculate using parsing variable

Tags: php, parsing, variables, calculator

This is a calculator using php variables and parsing. What I enter for the variables in the url is the same thing as entering them in the form. And when I click submit, it should calculate. But I don't know where it's wrong (did not properly assign variables?) Thank you so much!

*Here are my problems:*
**1. Where should I fix for it to calculate properly?
2. How do I change the actual table padding and table border of the page by entering them into the form?
3. How do I change the background colours of the table using a variable that I pass from the URL?**

```
<?php
// parse variables from URLs
echo "This is the value of <b>x:</b>  " . $_GET['x'] . ". This is the value of <b>y: </b> " . $_GET['y'] . ".This is the value of <b>z: </b>  " . $_GET['z'] . " , And the title is: " . $_GET['title'] . ".";
?>

<?
$result1 = $x + $y - 2*$z;
$result2 = 2*$x + 4*$y + (3*$z - 80);
$result3 = $result1 + $result2; 
?>

<center><h2> Math </h2></center>
<center> 
<table  cellpadding=20  border=20 bgcolor=#00ffff  >  
<tr>
<td><b>Mathematical Operation</b></td>
<td><b>Result</b></td>  
</tr>

<tr>
<td>x + y - 2 * z</td>
<td><?echo "$result1";?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2x - 4y + (3z - 80)</td>
<td><?echo "$result2";?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Row2 - Col2 + result of Row3 - Col2</td>
<td><?echo "$result3";?></td>
</tr>
</table> 
</center>

<form>
<u>Inputs:</u> <br />
X-value <input type="text" name="x" value=""></input><br />
Y-Value <input type="text" name="y" value=""></input><br />
Z-Value <input type="text" name="z" value=""></input><br />
Title <input type="text" name="title" value=""></input><br />
Table Padding <input type="text" name="pad" value=""></input><br />
Table Border <input type="text" name="brdr" value=""></input><br />
Background Color <input type="color" name="bckrd" value=""></input><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT and CALCULATE"></input>
</form>

<?
if ($_GET['submit']) {  
$result1 = $x + $y - 2*$z;
$result2 = 2*$x + 4*$y + (3*$z - 80);
$result3 = $result1 + $result2;     
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to actually declare the variables you're using and assign them values:

   `$x = $_GET['x'];`

   `$y = $_GET['y'];`

   `$z = $_GET['z'];`

   `$result1 = $x + $y - 2*$z;`

   `$result2 = 2*$x + 4*$y + (3*$z - 80);`

   `$result3 = $result1 + $result2;`
2. Same idea as above and rest of your form, here's one way. Add this to your form:

   `Padding: <input type="text" name="tblpadding" value="1"></input><br />
   Border width: <input type="text" name="tblwidth" value="1"></input><br />
   Colour: <input type="text" name="tblcolour" value="#ccc"></input><br />`

Then, in your PHP code:

```
$tblPadding = $_GET['tblpadding'];
$tblWidth = $_GET['tblwidth'];
$tblColour = $_GET['tblcolour'];
```

Then, change your `<table>` declaration to this:
`<table cellpadding="<?php echo $tblPadding; ?> border="<?php echo $tblWidth; ?>" bgcolor="<?php echo $tblColour;">`

3. See answer in #2, I added it in there.

Comment: Sorry about the horrible formatting, can't figure out how to properly format entire code block within list items, the indentation doesn't seem to work :/